# ClojureScript map destructure with defaults filled in?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, destructuring

Does Clojure/Script offer a way to build a destructured map out of the arguments plus filled-in defaults in case the keys weren't supplied in the call?

Consider this example (that doesn't quite do what the code implies by a quick glance). Does clojure provide  a way to build the map `prompt` with these four keys and values either from the caller or the defaults. I hate to think I have to repeat these key names two more times to get what I am after.

```
(re-frame/reg-event-db
 :open-prompt
 (fn [db [_ {title :title
             text :text
             label-yes :label-yes
             label-no :label-no
             :or {title "Confirm"
                  text "Are you sure?"
                  label-yes "Ok"
                  label-no "Cancel"}
             :as prompt}]]
   (-> db
       (update :state conj :modal-prompt)
       (assoc :prompt prompt))))
```

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing the [official documentation page about destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring), I don't think that Clojure proposes a more convient way of doing that.

But just by curiosity, I was wondering what is the code generated by destructuring, because I'm expecting it relies on macro stuff. Let consider this toy example:

```
(def my-map {:text "Some text"})
(let
  [{title :title
    :or {title "Confirm"}
    :as prompt} my-map]
  (str "I got " title " from " prompt))
;; => "I got Confirm from {:text \"Some text\"}"

(macroexpand '(let
                  [{title :title
                    :or {title "Confirm"}
                    :as prompt} my-map]
                (str "I got " title " from " prompt)))
;; => (let*
;;     [map__12555
;;      my-map
;;      map__12555
;;      (if
;;          (clojure.core/seq? map__12555)
;;        (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create
;;         (clojure.core/seq map__12555))
;;        map__12555)
;;      prompt
;;      map__12555
;;      title
;;      (clojure.core/get map__12555 :title "Confirm")]
;;     (str "I got " title " from " prompt))
```

So as you can see, after a macro expansion, the `:or` mechanism which allows to specifies default value relies on `clojure.core/get`.

In this particular example, `title` is affected by `(clojure.core/get map__12555 :title "Confirm")` form. It's a way to avoid repeating the `title` variable, but does it worth it?

You can also check the [source code of the destructuring macro](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/30a36cbe0ef936e57ddba238b7fa6d58ee1cbdce/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4391) to get full details about it, but personally I found it pretty difficult to handle ^^'.

Answer (score 2):

I like to make a map of all default values, then use `into` or similar to fuse the user-supplied values into the map of default values.  For example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test) )

(def stuff-default {:a 1 :b 2})

(defn apply-defaults
  [arg]
  (let [stuff (glue stuff-default arg)] ; or use `into`.  Last one wins, so put defaults first
    (with-map-vals stuff [a b]
      (newline)
      (spyx a)
      (spyx b))
    stuff))

(dotest
  (is= (apply-defaults {}) ; no inputs => all default values
    {:a 1, :b 2})
  (is= (apply-defaults {:a 100}) ; some inputs => partial defaults
    {:a 100, :b 2})
  (is= (apply-defaults {:a 100, :b 200}) ; all inputs => no defaults used
    {:a 100, :b 200}))
```

Here `glue` is like `into` but with more error checking.  We also use `tupelo.core/with-map-vals` to destruct the map, with less repetition than native Clojure destructuring (`vals->map` does the reverse).

The output is:

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 14
-------------------------------

a => 1
b => 2

a => 100
b => 2

a => 100
b => 200

Ran 2 tests containing 3 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

Answer (score 2):

it is doable, maybe not very practical though, but nice for self education:

let's begin with making up the function what would be special binding case.

let's say, we want to pass vectors of length 2 or 3, where vector of 2 will represent the simple binding map key-value pair like `[:as abc]` or `[a :a]`, and the vector of size 3 would be k-v-default triple: `[a :a "my default"]`. The example of it's usage:

```
(bindings-preproc [['a 1 "asd"]
                   ['b 2 "ddd"]
                   [:or {'x 10}]
                   [:as 'whole]])
```

resulting to

```
{a 1, b 2, :or {x 10, a "asd", b "ddd"}, :as whole}
```

this function could look like this:

```
(defn bindings-preproc [decls]
  (let [defaults (into {} (keep (fn [decl]
                                  (when (and (not (keyword? (first decl)))
                                             (= 3 (count decl)))
                                    (let [[nm _ default] decl]
                                      [nm default])))
                                decls))
        all-kvs (apply assoc {} (mapcat (partial take 2) decls))]
    (update all-kvs :or merge defaults)))
```

(this one doesn't include error checks for the sake of illustrative simplicity)

The next thing is to employ it inside the binding macros. The idea to make `bindings-preproc` a macro fails, because binding forms are checked for validity *before* the inner macros are evaluated.

But still we have a feature, that would help, namely [reader tags](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*data-readers*). They are used for example when you use `#inst` syntax. Since these reader tags are processed at read-time, before any macros are getting expanded, we can plug our preprocessor in.

(here i will use actual reference update, to demonstrate it from repl, but in real projects you would declare these tags in a special file)

```
user> (alter-var-root
       #'default-data-readers
       assoc 'my/reader #'user/bindings-preproc)

;;=> {uuid #'clojure.uuid/default-uuid-reader,
;;    inst #'clojure.instant/read-instant-date,
;;    my/reader #'user/bindings-preproc}
```

so, now we can try to make it work:

```
(defn f [#my/reader [[a :a 10]
                     [b :b 20]
                     [z :z]
                     [:keys [k1 k2 k3]]
                     [[c1 c2 & cs] :c]
                     [:or {z 101
                           k3 :wooo}]
                     [:as whole]]]
  {:a a :b b :c1 c1 :c2 c2 :cs cs :z z :k1 k1 :k2 k2 :k3 k3 :whole whole})

user> (f {:a 1000 :c [:one]})
;;=> {:cs nil,
;;    :c2 nil,
;;    :z 101,
;;    :c1 :one,
;;    :k3 :wooo,
;;    :b 20,
;;    :whole {:a 1000, :c [:one]},
;;    :k1 nil,
;;    :k2 nil,
;;    :a 1000}


user> (let [a 10
            b 20
            #my/reader [[x :x 1]
                        [y :y 2]
                        [z :z 100]] {:z 432}]
        [a b x y z])
;;=> [10 20 1 2 432]
```